# Fast replacement of a string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am revamping an e-commerce site using a system that allows fast product upload via CSV files. I am using Microsoft Excel 2007. The manufacturers have supplied me with a spreadsheet containing the product details, and also all the relevant product images, which are named with the product reference number.

So, I have a CSV file with a column of reference numbers, and a column with the paths to the images, e.g. 'images/products/1234567890.jpg'.

How can I quickly replace the reference numbers in the image column with the relevant reference numbers from the ref. no. column?

EDIT:

I've solved it! Simpler than I thought, you just need a formula:

```
="path/to/images/"&Column Reference&".jpg"
```

Then simply copy and paste the formula into the entire column.

Thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the image column "images/products/1234567890.jpg" to reflect the reference column "images/products/REFERENCE.jpg".

You could use a macro.
Here is an example: [Find and Replace](http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/859446-solved-macro-multiple-find-replace.html)

Comment: Yes, I just want to take the reference number and insert it between the / and .jpg. I'll have a look at the macro and see if I can get it to work, thanks.